# redirect traffic of all websites apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

how can I redirect traffic of all websites (and not one of them) to a page in apache2 conf file?

the goal is creating a maintenance page for all domains.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^ /maintenance.html [R=301]
```

This should redirect all requests to the `maintenance.html` page.

Comment: the goal is creating a maintenance page for "all domains". this not work for all of them.

Comment: @exim This *does* work for all domains but you will have to put it in a part of your configuration that applies to all domains.  If you have one vhost per domain, putting this in just one of them will not work.  I would also avoid using a 301 redirect, or even a redirect at all.  Just serve up the maintenance page under the URL that was requested with a 503 response code.

Comment: @Ladadadada I know that solution but I want a better solution for all vhosts to use in a cronjob before proccessing schedule backups

Comment: It's generally a good idea to put *all* of your requirements in the question to save this back-and-forth extraction process.

Comment: @Khaled Nice answer, although a 301 redirect to a maintenance page would be killing for your SEO if a crawler would come by at that point. I know it's just an example, but this is just a note to anyone who considers implementing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

To easily change many vhosts, add this to all of them (you only need to do this once):

```
Include maintenance-status.conf
```

Add something like @Khaled's answer in `/etc/apache2/maintenance-on.conf`.

Create a symlink at `/etc/apache2/maintenance-status.conf` pointing at `/etc/apache2/maintenance-off.conf`, which should be an empty file.

In your cron job, simply repoint that link at the beginning and end and give Apache a graceful restart after each one.

It might be better to do this in PHP (or whatever scripting language you use) and trigger it with a file or a database entry if you can.

Comment: good solution but I can not use such rewrite commands that khaled said in a conf file. those works in local .htaccess file and pointed to local file (index.html). even if I do it, then how I discard all other rewrite mod commands came from local htaccesses?